# Does a Gnome Mystic who replaces WIS save with an alternate attribute still have advantage on the save?

Tags: dnd-5e, unearthed-arcana

Gnomes are given advantage on WIS saves against Magic. 4th Level Psionic Mystics (UA) have the ability to:

> replace your proficiency in Wisdom saving throws whenever you finish a short or long rest. To do    so, choose Strength, Dexterity, Constitution, or Charisma. You gain proficiency in saves using that ability, instead of Wisdom.

This allows you to make your WIS save using a different Ability Score, but do you still get the Gnome Advantage even though you're not using your Wisdom even though technically it is a WIS save?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, there's no Wisdom save happening in that case. The ability doesn't let you make a non-Wisdom save you are about to suffer using your Wisdom. All the Mystic is doing is losing Wisdom save proficiency and gaining a different save proficiency. You treat this as a normal proficiency at that point.

Meanwhile, being a gnome continues to grant advantage on Wisdom saves. If you've switched your proficiency to Dexterity (perhaps you're planning on climbing an ice cliff?) and you have to make a Wisdom save against magic, you'll still make it with the advantage granted by **Gnome Cunning**, but without any class proficiency.